# Ink outline vs seniority of color layers

Tags: layers, drawing, outline, ink, layer-composition

New to digital drawing, but would imagine that everyone starts with a sketched ink outline that has an alpha channel, and then from there add on color layers to fill in the transparent space between the inks as one sees fit.

Would you say that the color layers should be moved forward in front of the base ink outline layer? Or is it better to make the ink outline layer the foremost layer in front of the color layers? and should every color layer have an alpha channel like the ink layer?

Comment: Your assumption seems like it does not necceserily hold for all workflows

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There are many ways to work with digital drawings, many techniques and workflows. None of these you listed are a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" answer here.

Use whatever works for you.

There is *some* benefit to having the keyline above color layers... you don't have to be as precise with edges on the color layers. However, you can always reorder layers if necessary, so..... it really does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could even not need any alpha transparency. You could use multiply blending mode.

You should avoid using the word should... A tool is a tool, meaning that you use them as you need them, as you need it.